# Is there a way to GUARANTEE non-blocking reads in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have tried the obvious "SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED", but my simple stored procedure still gets blocked while doing a SELECT MAX on a PRIMARY KEY while updates are going on (when running simultaneously with certain complex update transactions that I do not want to modify) -- ultimately running into Deadlocks and Lock Timeouts.

Surely there must be a way to GUARANTEE a non-blocking read... And I thought that was the purpose of READ-UNCOMMITTED. But I was wrong... Is this a MySQL bug? Is there a work-around?

I am aware of all the dangers and academically unsound properties of READ-UNCOMMITTED, but that doesn't matter, for my particular application an occasional phantom or missing row here and there is really no big deal, but the delay or error caused by the read-locks is a much more serious matter.

All tables in the database are InnoDB.
Server version is 5.0.67. Platform is Linux 32-bit.

***UPDATE*** Here's a simplified "hello world" version of the problem description (my actual queries are too complex and ugly to post):

CONSOLE 1:

```
mysql> create table t1(a int primary key) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.20 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 values (1),(2),(3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into t1 values (4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> update t1 set a=5 where a=4;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

CONSOLE 2 (in separate window, do not close CONSOLE 1)

```
mysql> select max(a) from t1;
+--------+
| max(a) |
+--------+
|      3 | 
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @test = (select max(a) from t1);
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Comment: do you have indexes to 'cover' your query workload?

Comment: Mitch: the simple query which is at the focus of my investigation is indexed enough to cover the WHERE conditions, but not all the returned columns.

Comment: Your reads are non-blocking here, it's the INSERTs and UPDATEs that are blocking.  There's no way to get around this without a master-slave setup or similar, or modifying the long-running UPDATEs as James suggests.

Comment: Ben: Your assumption is incorrect. I have got to the bottom of this with "show engine innodb status", and it is absolutely the case, that my reads are not non-blocking (i.e. THE READS ARE IN FACT BEING BLOCKED). Everything we have ever read about InnoDB is wrong :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it:

**"Is this a MySQL bug?"** --> Yes, I'd call it a bug. Others may call it a limitation or a "Gotcha". I'd call it a BUG because clearly the theoretical basis as well as practical capability of retrieving this data without a lock is evidenced by the existence of a mostly syntactical workaround.

**"Is there a workaround?"** --> Yes.

Rewriting this

```
set @test = (select max(a) from t1);
```

as this

```
select max(a) from t1 into @test;
```

produces the same result when the other transaction is not running; and produces the expected result (value is retrieved successfully and immediately, instead of dying on a lock) when the other transaction IS running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make certain that your updates will never be blocked by your selects, then I would suggest having two databases, where the master is where inserts/updates take place, and through replication the data is sent to the slave, where you do your selects.

This should limit any problems from selects, as the replication is very fast, so your selects can be as complicated as you want, and it will never impact the updates.

Unfortunately, even if you just had row locking, you may still have problems, as one query is writing to a table while trying to read from that table.

**Update:** Before you downvote, he just recently put up the queries and error message, so now he can help help on the problem, so my responses aren't wrong, for what he started with.

Comment: My problem is selects being blocked by updates, not the other way around as you state above. Also it turns out my selects are simple, it's the updates that are complex. Anyway replication is very expensive (not just the hardware, but mostly the admin time!) so I sure hope there is a better way. Also I suspect statement-based replication would not solve anything, since the same updates would run on the slave.

Comment: If you are doing an insert then how will select Max(...) find the new row unless the insert was done? You are correct though that replication won't help if the problem is inserts blocking selects. Once you have replication set up the admin time is very minimal.  Can you show a sample of a select and insert/update?

Comment: James: finding the new row is not the issue. I could care less whether the latest uncommitted row is included in the resultset or not. All I want is some resultset, with uncomitted row or not, it would be better than the Lock Timeout. The actual select is SET @LastImport = (select MAX(IMPORT_FILE_DATE) from idx_datafeed_file_commit); the conflicting insert/update is too ugly to post here, I'll have to come up with a "hello world" version.

Comment: Thanks for your help... if you didn't keep insisting that I had to post the queries, I would not have created the simplified "hello world" example which made the problem and workaround much easier to finally identify.

Comment: You should post the solution, btw, in case someone else gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB SELECTs are normally non-locking by default (such that they can run with as many DML statements as you can throw at it).  So it seems like something other than just normal SELECTs and DML statements are going on.

Perhaps you are doing an INSERT...SELECT statement or something like that?  Can you post your stored procedure?

Comment: It was not an INSERT...SELECT; just a regular INSERT followed by UPDATES, that are holding the lock on the other session.